# Iterate following a path/branch: Networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to iterate over each of the branches of the graph attached.

This is the graph created:

```
A = nx.DiGraph()

A.add_node('S1', e=1)
A.add_node('S2', e=2)
A.add_node('S3', e=3)
A.add_node('S4', e=4)
A.add_node('S5', e=5)
A.add_node('S6', e=6)
A.add_node('S7', e=7)
A.add_node('S8', e=8)

A.add_edges_from([('S1','S2'),
                  ('S2','S3'),
                  ('S2','S4'),
                  ('S4','S5'),
                  ('S3','S6'),
                  ('S5','S8'),
                  ('S6','S7'),
                  ('S7','S8')])
```

[image]

What I would like to do is:

1. To detect when two paths start from a single node (This is done already)
2. To iterate over the attributes of each of the paths. First iterating in one of the branches/paths and then iterate over the other path. In the graph I created this would be: First iterate over the attributes of the branch: S3-S6-S7 and then the branch S4-S5.
   I stop iterating when the inbound degree of the node (in this case S8) is greater than 1.

The code I have so far does not go over the whole branch, and I don't know how to solve it.

```
nodes = A.nodes(data=True)

for succ in A.neighbors('S2'):
    print(nodes[succ]['e'])
    for node in A.neighbors(succ):
        print(nodes[node]['e'])
        if A.in_degree(node) > 1:
            break
Output:
3
6
4
5
```

PD: My apologies if there are big mistakes, I have just started with Python and Networkx...

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do in the end? E.g. `list(nx.all_simple_paths(A, source='S1', target='S8'))` will already happily get you the two paths from S1 to S8: `['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5', 'S8']`

Comment: I would like to get the sum of the attributes of each branch

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get the sum of the attributes of each branch

This will output the sum of each path, if that's what you're looking for.

```
import networkx as nx

A = nx.DiGraph()

A.add_node("S1", e=1)
A.add_node("S2", e=2)
A.add_node("S3", e=3)
A.add_node("S4", e=4)
A.add_node("S5", e=5)
A.add_node("S6", e=6)
A.add_node("S7", e=7)
A.add_node("S8", e=8)

A.add_edges_from(
    [
        ("S1", "S2"),
        ("S2", "S3"),
        ("S2", "S4"),
        ("S4", "S5"),
        ("S3", "S6"),
        ("S5", "S8"),
        ("S6", "S7"),
        ("S7", "S8"),
    ]
)

for path in nx.all_simple_paths(A, source="S1", target="S8"):
    print(path, sum(A.nodes[n]["e"] for n in path))
```

outputs

```
['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8'] 27
['S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5', 'S8'] 20
```

Comment: I am trying now doing all_simple_paths with edges instead of nodes, and it doesn't seem to work:

`for path in nx.all_simple_paths(A, source="S1", target="S8"):
    print(path, sum(A[u][v]["e"] for u,v in path))`

Comment: @M.Mike There is a networkx primitive summing all weights of a path for you: for path in nx.all_simple_paths(A, source="S1", target="S8"):
print(path, nx.path_weight(A, path, "e"))